# copy output of fprintf to print at restart of code in C

Tags: c

I am new to coding, but I managed to print my current local time and date. I was wondering if I am able to save the whole output from the code below to print that same info without changing it when I rerun the program.

```c
switch (month)
{
    case 0:
        strcat(m,"01");
        break;
    case 1:
        strcat(m,"02");
        break;
    case 2:
        strcat(m,"03");
        break;
    case 3:
        strcat(m,"04");
        break;
    case 4:
        strcat(m,"05");
        break;
    case 5:
        strcat(m,"06");
        break;
    case 6:
        strcat(m,"07");
        break;
    case 7:
        strcat(m,"08");
        break;
    case 8:
        strcat(m,"09");
        break;
    case 9:
        strcat(m,"10");
        break;
    case 10:
        strcat(m,"11");
        break;
    case 11:
        strcat(m,"12");
        break;
        
    }
year=year+1900;        //Making Current year
fprintf(stderr, "Time Logout (YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS):\n%d:%s:%d:%2d:%2d:%2d\n",year,m,wd,hr,mn,sc);
```

this is not the whole thing code, but so far it does print out like this.
2021:11:5:11:20: 3

I would like to save this outcome to print out at the top of my program when I rerun it then update it to the current time like how it is now, at the end before I close out of the program.

Comment: If you want to persist data across invocations of your program, then you can write that data to file (or a database). Also, why are you printing to stderr rather than stdout?

Comment: Your `switch` block can be replaced with: `sprintf( m + strlen( m ), "0%u", m + 1 );`

Comment: You really should try `sprintf()` to get rid of that long tower of `if`'s. I believe that wont be too difficult for you.

Comment: To print month : use %02d and month+1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the switch can be replaced with:

```
sprintf(m+strlen(m), "%02d", month);
```

Secondly, put that `fprintf` call in a function:

```
static void printDate(FILE* output, int year, char const* m, int wd, int hr, int mn, int sc) {
   fprintf(output, "Time Logout (YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS):\n%d:%s:%d:%2d:%2d:%2d\n",year,m,wd,hr,mn,sc);
}
```

Then call it with `stdout` for normal output, `stderr` for the error output, or pass any other stream of importance.